# Using a launch screen (.xib) stops scaling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode-storyboard

It's my understanding that apps for iOS 8 should have a storyboard file as launch screen rather than an image. I've created a really simple launch screen file that has any width and any height, and has one label of plain text reading "placeholder" and set it as my launch screen. However, when I try to run my app on the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus simulators, there's black bars around the background and the buttons on the main menu are out of place. The problem doesn't seem to be present in the 5s or iPad. Most of my assets aren't optimized for the 6 and 6 Plus though, since they were created before they came out. Is that why this is happening? Or is it something else? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Apparently, putting in a launch screen stops the app from automatically scaling. Is there a way to have both a launch screen, and keep the app scaling? Or do I need to make new assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of an old question, and I ended up using a launch image instead of a launch screen, but you can probably solve this by using constraints. If you set top, bottom, leading, and/or trailing constraints on an item in the view, it'll scale itself to fit those constraints (if possible). For text, it has the autoshrink property which you can change to minimum font scale (instead of fixed font size), though I'm not sure how you can scale text up. The autolayout documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1).

Answer (score -1):

To create a launch screen from a xib file first create a new file from under “User Interface” and select the option called “Launch Screen”

[image: create launch screen file]

Using autolayout, design the first view of you app so it scales to suit all resolutions that your app supports.

Using the new Launch Screen

Under the app setting select the newly created Launch Screen from the app options.

[image: select Launch Screen File]

This is the example for using a xib file. It can also be done using storyboard as shown in [Ole Begemann blog](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/)

Comment: I already know how to create a launch screen, the problem is that when I use it, the interface on the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus becomes messed up.

Comment: Do the images with in the launch screen contain @x3 images or standard @x2?

Comment: There aren't any images, it's just placeholder text.

Comment: "Using autolayout, design the first view of you app so it scales to suit all resolutions that your app supports."   Stupid question, but how?  I don't see any controls to cause the view to swell to fill the screen.

Comment: @Ian Ollmann did you guys figure this out yet?.. I am having the same issue

Comment: I have no idea. In my case, it just started scaling on its own. Maybe I had a bug that prevented it and I fixed it on the way to fixing something else?